# meanings of gc log when promotion failure

Tags: java, jvm

What does the following gc log mean when `promotion failure` occurs?

```
2019-07-24T23:58:32.113+0800: 1731400.358: [ParNew 
(0: promotion failure size = 3)
(1: promotion failure size = 2)  
(2: promotion failure size = 2)
(3: promotion failure size = 2)  
(4: promotion failure size = 3)
(6: promotion failure size = 2)  
(7: promotion failure size = 65538)
(8: promotion failure size = 2)  
(9: promotion failure size = 9)
(0: promotion failure size = 3)  
(1: promotion failure size = 2)
(2: promotion failure size = 2)  
(3: promotion failure size = 2)
(4: promotion failure size = 3)
(6: promotion failure size = 2)
(7: promotion failure size = 65538)
(8: promotion failure size = 2)
(9: promotion failure size = 9)
(0: promotion failure size = 3)
(1: promotion failure size = 2)
(2: promotion failure size = 2)
(3: promotion failure size = 2)
(4: promotion failure size = 3)
(6: promotion failure size = 2)
(7: promotion failure size = 65538)
(8: promotion failure size = 2)
(9: promotion failure size = 9)
(0: promotion failure size = 3)
(1: promotion failure size = 2)
(2: promotion failure size = 2)
(3: promotion failure size = 2)
(4: promotion failure size = 3)
(6: promotion failure size = 2)
(7: promotion failure size = 65538)
(8: promotion failure size = 2)
(9: promotion failure size = 9)
(0: promotion failure size = 3)
(1: promotion failure size = 2)
(2: promotion failure size = 2)
(3: promotion failure size = 2)
(4: promotion failure size = 3)
(6: promotion failure size = 2)
(7: promotion failure size = 65538)
(8: promotion failure size = 2)
(9: promotion failure size = 9)
(0: promotion failure size = 3)
(1: promotion failure size = 2)
(2: promotion failure size = 2)
(3: promotion failure size = 2)
(4: promotion failure size = 3)
(6: promotion failure size = 2)
(7: promotion failure size = 65538)
(8: promotion failure size = 2)
(9: promotion failure size = 9)
(0: promotion failure size = 3)
```

I use *parNew* + *CMS*.

**JDK 1.8_102**

Comment: Which GC algorithm do you use?

Comment: I use parNew + CMS. jdk8

Answer (score 1):

**Promotion failure** occurs when garbage collection cannot find enough (contiguous) space in the old generation into which to promote an object from the new generation.

The simple solution is increase old generation heap size. [This doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html) help to you.

The other solution, use GC1 algorithm with **-XX:+UseG1GC** flag. Because *G1 GC* more successful than *CMS* in old generation fragmentation. [Oracle doc](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html) say:

> The G1 GC reduces heap fragmentation by incremental parallel copying of live objects from one or more sets of regions (called Collection Set (CSet)) into different new region(s) to achieve compaction. The goal is to reclaim as much heap space as possible, starting with those regions that contain the most reclaimable space, while attempting to not exceed the pause time goal (garbage first).